# Forcing "ct" ligature for Google Web Fonts

Tags: css, unicode, google-font-api, google-fonts, ligature

I'm using the font IM Fell English for my project: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/IM+Fell+English?selection.family=IM+Fell+English

It has support for the "long s" ſ, and other common ligatures such as "ff", "fi", "ft", etc.

However, I can't seem to get "ct" ligature working, albeit you can see that the font does have the glyph: here 1) https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/im-fell-english-pro and here 2) https://iginomarini.com/fell/the-revival-fonts/

I have tried `font-variant-ligatures` CSS property as directed here, but it does not work regardless of which value I set: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-ligatures

My current compromise is to replace the "s" with "ſ" Unicode character, but as far as I know, there is no such Unicode character for the "ct" ligature (nor a joiner glyph) (as far as I could find!)

Additionally, to get the long ſ to work, I had to `@import` the font in such way:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IM+Fell+English:400,400i&subset=all&text=+!%22%23$%25%26()*%2B,-.%2F0123456789:;%3C%3D%3E%3F@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ%5B%5C%5Dabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz%7B%7D%C2%A2%C2%A3%C2%A5%C2%A9%C2%AE%C3%97%C3%B7%C5%BF%E2%80%98%E2%80%99%E2%80%9C%E2%80%9D%E2%82%AC');
```

The method which I obtained the value for the `text` parameter was that I inputted the long ſ into the preview field on the Google Font webpage for IM Fell English (the first link above), and then I watch which request my browser sent out and copied it.

As you can see below, I am much in need of re-creating this! (Notice the "ct" in "Octaves"; I've taken care of the long ſ in the titles, but not the paragraphs)

Recreation: 
[image: screenshot of the recreation of an old text]
Original Source:
[image: original source of an old text]

---

**Edit: I've found a workaround.**
I downloaded the IM Fell English font, then use Character Map (which is available under Windows 10), and search for the glyph and copied it (U+E004 Private Use). The trouble now is that I cannot search (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd>) for anything that contains the ligature! So, I cannot search for "Octaves" because it is now "Oaves".

I believe the original question in the title still stands. I don't want a workaround, I want to have the browser force the ligature, if that's possible.

Comment: Not a programming problem, off-topic for SO. Edit the font to offer a ligature when c followed by t is to be displayed. This works on the font rendering level, not the Unicode level, so will preserve search. See http://www.sansbullshitsans.com/ for an amusing demo.

Comment: @daxim The font does offer the ligature when you download it from its original website, and enable ligature in Microsoft Word. However, this is not the case for Google Fonts. This is possibly a Google Fonts specific question, but I haven't tried downloading the font and applying the CSS rule mentioned in the question above.

Comment: Google Fonts trims quite a lot “uncommon” OpenType features for their web font hosting, Discretionary Ligature is one of them. To solve this, you might want to find a different source or host the font yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Eana Hufwe google will by default strip additional substitution features when requesting the font via API.  instead you get a subset matching the current language on your page (or more exactly the text used in it)

### 1. Fetch complete "un-substituted" woff2

You can fetch the complete woff2 file using the dev API. In the following example I'm using a static copy of the JSON response. Aquiring an API key is free and pretty straight forward (See [the documentation.](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/developer_api#APIKey)) and provides the most up-to-date font list from google.

```js
/*
//if you obtained an API key use this dynamic query URL
let format = 'woff2'
let apiKey = "";
let apiURL = `https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?capability=VF&capability=${format}&sort=style&key=${apiKey}`;
*/

let apiURL = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/herrstrietzel/fonthelpers@main/json/gfontsAPI_woff2.json";


// get font item
let fontFamily = "IM Fell English";
let familyQuery = fontFamily.replaceAll(" ", "+");
let fontList

( async()=>{
  fontList =  await (await (await fetch(apiURL)).json() ).items;
  //get data options
  populateDatalist(fontsDataOptions, fontList)

  //init
  inputFont.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))

})()

inputFont.addEventListener('change', e=>{
  fontFamily = inputFont.value
  let item = fontList.filter(item => item.family === fontFamily)[0];
  let fontUrl = item.files.regular
  
  a_woff2.href = fontUrl
  a_woff2.textContent = fontUrl
  
})

function populateDatalist(target, list) {
  let datalistOptions = "";
  list.forEach((font) => {
      datalistOptions += `<option >${font.family}</option>`;
  });
  target.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", datalistOptions);
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Get font from API </legend>
  <input id="inputFont" type="text" list="fontsDataOptions" value="IM Fell English" placeholder="Search for google font">
  <datalist id="fontsDataOptions"></datalist>


</fieldset>
<p><strong>Woff font URL: </strong>
  <a id="a_woff2" href=""></a>
</p>
```

### 2. Inspect font-features

Drop your font in the UI helper [wakamaifondue.com](https://wakamaifondue.com/).
This tool will show you all available features of this font as well as a stylesheet including all CSS `font-feature-settings`

[image]

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "IM Fell English";
  src: url('https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/imfellenglish/v14/Ktk1ALSLW8zDe0rthJysWrnLsAz3EqmZVY9Y5w.woff2');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal
}

body {
  font-size: 8vw;
  font-family: "IM Fell English";
}

.im-fell-english-roman-dlig {
  font-feature-settings: "dlig" on;
  /* font-variant-ligatures: discretionary-ligatures; */
}

.im-fell-english-roman-ss01 {
  font-feature-settings: "ss01" on;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="im-fell-english-roman-dlig">
    ct ſs
</span>
  <span class="im-fell-english-roman-ss01">
    sa sb sc sd se sf sg sh si sj sk sl sm sn so sp sq sr ss st su sv sw sx sy sz sà sá sâ sã sä så sæ sç sè sé sê së sì sí sî sï sð sñ sò só sô sõ sö sø sù sú sû sü sý sþ sÿ sā să są sć sč sď sđ sē sė sę sě sğ sģ sī sį sķ sĺ sļ sľ sł sń sņ sň sō ső sœ sŕ sŗ sř sś sş sš sţ sť sū sů sű sų sŵ sŷ sź sż sž sș sẁ sẃ sẅ sỳ
</span>
</p>

<h3>No features appllied</h3>
<p>
    ct ſs
    sa sb sc sd se sf sg sh si sj sk sl sm sn so sp sq sr ss st su sv sw sx sy sz sà sá sâ sã sä så sæ sç sè sé sê së sì sí sî sï sð sñ sò só sô sõ sö sø sù sú sû sü sý sþ sÿ sā să są sć sč sď sđ sē sė sę sě sğ sģ sī sį sķ sĺ sļ sľ sł sń sņ sň sō ső sœ sŕ sŗ sř sś sş sš sţ sť sū sů sű sų sŵ sŷ sź sż sž sș sẁ sẃ sẅ sỳ
</p>
```

You can apply this method also for google fonts supporting special glyphs like arrows, symbols etc (e.g IBM Plex).